# Присваивание значения методу структуры

Tags: c++

Как присвоить методу структуры какое-то значение?
например ref.get() = 15;

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Покажите, как объявлена эта структура, и чего вы хотите добиться этим присваиванием. `get` - это указатель на функцию и вы хотите заменить его другой функцией? Это метод, возвращающий ссылку? Или вы просто хотите, чтобы при следующем вызове функция вернула 15?

Answer (score 2):

То, что вы написали, является не "присваиванием методу", а присваиванием результату вызова функции-члена. Это вполне возможно, если функция-член возвращает ссылку, например:

```
struct T {
    int i;
    int& get() { return i; }
};
```

В этом случае ваше присваивание `ref.get() = 15` будет просто присваиванием 15 члену `i`.